# How can I prevent both the keyboard and the menu from being shown together?

Tags: java, android, android-softkeyboard, android-menu, android-searchmanager

Here's a screenshot of my application. When the search box is clicked, the soft-keyboard automatically pops up, which is fine, but, if I also press the "Menu" button, the menu appears on top of the soft-keyboard.

How can I show the menu but collapse the `SearchView` if it is in focus and also hide the soft-keyboard. I probably need to check and do something in the `onPrepareOptionsMenu` method of my `Activity`, right?

It doesn't cause any real harm to me but it seems like an ugly implementation to the user when this happens.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can call the `getCurrentFocus()` method from the searchView or override 
`onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasWindowFocus)` in your activity.

If that view is the searchview, then you can close the keyboard in this way:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
  Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(m_edittext.getWindowToken(), 0);
```